# how can I get Picasso and OkHttp to work together?

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp

I currently have the following libs added to the classpath (android project, minSDK 16):

- Picasso 2.3.3
- okhttp 2.0.0
- okhttp-urlconnection 2.0.0 RC1
- okio 1.0.1

Somehow Picasso refuses to work now and I'm getting the following error message:

```
  VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
  VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
 Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.sink
 VFY: unable to resolve static method 8759: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newOutputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/OutputStream;
 VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
 VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
 VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
 Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.source
 VFY: unable to resolve static method 8758: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newInputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/InputStream;
 VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a

 Could not find method com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient.setInternalCache, referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory.setResponseCache
  VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6548: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient;.setInternalCache (Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/InternalCache;)Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient;
 VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0009

 Could not find method com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient.setConnectTimeout, referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.setConnectTimeout
 VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6541: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient;.setConnectTimeout (JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient;
 VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0005
 Could not find method com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient.setReadTimeout, referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.setReadTimeout
 VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6553: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient;.setReadTimeout (JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)Lcom/squareu
```

Is there any way to get those libs to work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `okhttp-urlconnection 2.0.0`, not the RC1.

Comment: marking accepted since it doesn't crash anymore, but still getting those `unable to find class referenced in signature...` warnings. Any ideas? Oh and btw, does OkHttp have any advantages over android Volley?

Comment: You can ignore the verify warnings.